# Generating 15 minute time interval array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am trying to generate time interval array. for example:

```
time_array = ["2016-09-02T17:30:00Z", "2016-09-02T17:45:00Z", 
              "2016-09-02T18:00:00Z", "2016-09-02T18:15:00Z", 
              "2016-09-02T18:30:00Z", "2016-09-02T18:45:00Z"]
```

1. It should create the element like above in zulu time till 9 pm everyday.
2. Should generate the elements for next and day after next as well
3. Start time from 7:00 am - Ed time 9:00 pm,
   if current_time is > start_time then generate 15 min time interval array till 9 pm. and then generate for next day and day + 2.
   And Interval should be 7:00, 7:15 like that.. not in 7:12, 8:32

Comment: You have forgotten to show your attempts so far.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here's a generic `datetime_range` for you to use.

#### Code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta

dts = [dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d T%H:%M Z') for dt in 
       datetime_range(datetime(2016, 9, 1, 7), datetime(2016, 9, 1, 9+12), 
       timedelta(minutes=15))]

print(dts)
```

#### Output

> ['2016-09-01 T07:00 Z', '2016-09-01 T07:15 Z', '2016-09-01 T07:30 Z', '2016-09-01 T07:45 Z', '2016-09-01 T08:00 Z', '2016-09-01 T08:15 Z', '2016-09-01 T08:30 Z', '2016-09-01 T08:45 Z', '2016-09-01 T09:00 Z', '2016-09-01 T09:15 Z', '2016-09-01 T09:30 Z', '2016-09-01 T09:45 Z' ... ]

Comment: This solution is correct - however a word of caution for those that want to use this within a groupby. Since the datetime_range function returns a generator, it can only be used once.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) solution:

```
import pandas as pd

l = (pd.DataFrame(columns=['NULL'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-09-02T17:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T21:00:00Z',
                                      freq='15T'))
       .between_time('07:00','21:00')
       .index.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
       .tolist()
)
```

Output:

```
In [165]: l
Out[165]:
['2016-09-02T17:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T17:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T18:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T18:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T18:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T18:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T19:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T19:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T19:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T19:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T20:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T20:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T20:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T20:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-02T21:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T07:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T07:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T07:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T07:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T08:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T08:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T08:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T08:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T09:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T09:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T09:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T09:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T10:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T10:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T10:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T10:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T11:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T11:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T11:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T11:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T12:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T12:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T12:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T12:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T13:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T13:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T13:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T13:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T14:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T14:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T14:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T14:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T15:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T15:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T15:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T15:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T16:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T16:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T16:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T16:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T17:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T17:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T17:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T17:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T18:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T18:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T18:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T18:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T19:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T19:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T19:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T19:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T20:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T20:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T20:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T20:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-03T21:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T07:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T07:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T07:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T07:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T08:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T08:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T08:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T08:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T09:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T09:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T09:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T09:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T10:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T10:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T10:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T10:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T11:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T11:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T11:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T11:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T12:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T12:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T12:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T12:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T13:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T13:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T13:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T13:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T14:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T14:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T14:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T14:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T15:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T15:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T15:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T15:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T16:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T16:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T16:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T16:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T17:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T17:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T17:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T17:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T18:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T18:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T18:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T18:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T19:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T19:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T19:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T19:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T20:00:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T20:15:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T20:30:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T20:45:00Z',
 '2016-09-04T21:00:00Z']
```

Answer (score 17):

Looking at the data file, you should use the built in python date-time objects. followed by `strftime` to format your dates.

Broadly you can modify the code below to however many date-times you would like
First create a starting date.

```
Today= datetime.datetime.today()
```

Replace 100 with whatever number of time intervals you want.

```
date_list = [Today + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15*x) for x in range(0, 100)]
```

Finally, format the list in the way that you would like, using code like that below.

```
datetext=[x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d T%H:%M Z') for x in date_list]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @zhqiat for reply. I used some of your logic to make my script to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example using an arbitrary date time

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(1900,1,1,0,0,0)
end = datetime(1900,1,2,0,0,0)
```

Now you need to get the timedelta (the difference between two dates or times.) between the `start` and `end`

```
seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()
```

Define the 15 minutes interval

```
from datetime import timedelta

step = timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Iterate over the range of seconds, with step of time delta of 15 minutes (900 seconds) and sum it to `start`.

```
array = []
for i in range(0, int(seconds), int(step.total_seconds())):
    array.append(start + timedelta(seconds=i))

print array
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 15),
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 30),
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 45),
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 0),
...
```

At the end you can format the datetime objects to str representation.

```
array = [i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S') for i in array]

print array
['1900-01-01 00:00:00',
 '1900-01-01 00:15:00',
 '1900-01-01 00:30:00',
 '1900-01-01 00:45:00',
 '1900-01-01 01:00:00',
...
```

You can format datetime object at first iteration. But it may hurt your eyes

```
array.append((start + timedelta(seconds=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S'))
```

Comment: I liked the code and used your piece to develop my script as per requirement. Thank you mauro

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide a solution that does *not* handle timezones, since the problem is generating dates and times and you can set the timezone afterwards however you want.

You have a starting date and starting  and ending time (for each day), plus an interval (in minutes) for these datetimes. The idea is to create a `timedelta` object that represent the time interval and repeatedly update the datetime until we reach the ending time, then we advance by one day and reset the time to the initial one and repeat.

A simple implementation could be:

```
def make_dates(start_date, number_of_days, start_time, end_time, interval, timezone):
    if isinstance(start_date, datetime.datetime):
        start_date = start_date.date()
    start_date = datetime.datetime.combine(start_date, start_time)
    cur_date = start_date
    num_days_passed = 0
    step = datetime.timedelta(seconds=interval*60)

    while True:
        new_date = cur_date + step
        if new_date.time() > end_time:
            num_days_passed += 1
            if num_days_passed > number_of_days:
                break
            new_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=num_days_passed)
        ret_date, cur_date = cur_date, new_date
        yield ret_date

In [31]: generator = make_dates(datetime.datetime.now(), 3, datetime.time(hour=17), datetime.time(hour=19), 15, None)

In [32]: next(generator)
Out[32]: datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 17, 0)

In [33]: next(generator)
Out[33]: datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 17, 15)

In [34]: list(generator)
Out[34]: 
[datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 17, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 18, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 18, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 19, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 17, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 17, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 18, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 18, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 3, 19, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 17, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 17, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 18, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 18, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 4, 19, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 17, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 17, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 18, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 18, 45)]
```

Once you have the datetimes you can use the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) method to convert them to strings.

Comment: Thank you @Bakuriu. I posted the script which I developed from the posted answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final script I have written based on the answers posted on my question:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import calendar

current_utc = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")

current_year = int(current_utc.split("-")[0])
current_month = int(current_utc.split("-")[1])
current_date = int(current_utc.split("-")[2])
current_hour = int(current_utc.split("-")[3])
current_min = int(current_utc.split("-")[4])
current_sec = int(current_utc.split("-")[5])

#### To make minutes round to quarter ####
min_range_1 = range(1,16)
min_range_2 = range(16,31)
min_range_3 = range(31,46)
min_range_4 = range(46,60)

if current_min in min_range_1:
    current_min = 15
elif current_min in min_range_2:
    current_min = 30
elif current_min in min_range_3:
    current_min = 45
elif current_min in min_range_4:
    current_hour = current_hour + 1
    current_min = 0
else:
    print("Please check current minute.")

current_sec = 00

date_range_31 = range(1,32)
date_range_30 = range(1,31)

month_days_31 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
month_days_30 = [4,6,9,11]

if current_month in month_days_31:
    if current_date == 31:
        next_day_month = current_month + 1
        next_day_date = 1
    else:
        next_day_month = current_month
        next_day_date = current_date
elif current_month == 2:
    if calendar.isleap(current_year):
        if current_date == 29:
            next_day_month = current_month + 1
            next_day_date = 1
        else:
            next_day_month = current_month
            next_day_date = current_date
    else:
        if current_date == 28:
            next_day_month = current_month + 1
            next_day_date = 1
        else:
            next_day_month = current_month
            next_day_date = current_date
elif current_month in month_days_30:
    if current_date == 30:
        next_day_month = current_month + 1
        next_day_date = 1
    else:
        next_day_month = current_month
        next_day_date = current_date
else:
    print("Please check the current month and date to procedd further.")

if current_hour < 11:
    current_hour = 11
    current_min = 15
    next_day_date = current_date + 1

current_start = datetime(current_year,current_month,current_date,current_hour,current_min,current_sec)
current_end = datetime(current_year,current_month,current_date,21,15,0)

next_day_start = datetime(current_year,next_day_month,next_day_date,11,15,0)
next_day_end = datetime(current_year,next_day_month,next_day_date,21,15,0)

current_seconds = (current_end - current_start).total_seconds()
next_day_seconds = (next_day_end - next_day_start).total_seconds()

step = timedelta(minutes=15)

current_day_array = []
next_day_array = []

for i in range(0, int(current_seconds), int(step.total_seconds())):
    current_day_array.append(current_start + timedelta(seconds=i))

for i in range(0, int(next_day_seconds), int(step.total_seconds())):
    current_day_array.append(next_day_start + timedelta(seconds=i))

current_day_array = [i.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%:%SZ') for i in current_day_array]

print current_day_array
```

Which produces the following output:

```
['2016-09-03T11:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T11:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T11:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T12:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T12:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T12:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T12:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T13:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T13:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T13:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T13:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T14:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T14:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T14:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T14:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T15:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T15:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T15:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T15:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T16:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T16:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T16:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T16:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T17:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T17:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T17:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T17:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T18:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T18:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T18:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T18:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T19:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T19:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T19:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T19:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T20:00:00Z', '2016-09-03T20:15:00Z', '2016-09-03T20:30:00Z', '2016-09-03T20:45:00Z', '2016-09-03T21:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T11:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T11:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T11:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T12:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T12:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T12:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T12:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T13:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T13:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T13:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T13:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T14:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T14:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T14:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T14:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T15:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T15:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T15:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T15:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T16:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T16:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T16:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T16:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T17:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T17:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T17:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T17:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T18:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T18:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T18:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T18:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T19:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T19:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T19:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T19:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T20:00:00Z', '2016-09-04T20:15:00Z', '2016-09-04T20:30:00Z', '2016-09-04T20:45:00Z', '2016-09-04T21:00:00Z']
```

Comment: Note that StackOverflow Markdown is *not* GitHub flavor. So do not use the triple backquote for quote, just indent everything by 4 spaces (or just paste the code, select it and then press Ctrl+K or the `{}` button)