# Python Stacking datetime criteria

Tags: python, subset, criteria

I have a datetime dataframe like this:

```
1/1/2012 0:05
1/1/2012 0:10
1/1/2012 0:15
1/1/2012 0:20
1/1/2012 0:25
1/1/2012 0:30
1/1/2012 0:35
1/1/2012 0:40
1/1/2012 0:45
1/1/2012 0:50
1/1/2012 0:55
1/1/2012 1:00
1/1/2012 1:05
1/1/2012 1:10
1/1/2012 1:15
1/1/2012 1:20
```

continue til end of 2012. Was wondering how can I combine criteria to only choose date from,**for example 3/11 from 2am**. I'm thinking about using df.loc. Based on other threads I read before, it will combine them and delete a lot of data.
Thank you!

Comment: You have answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298054/generating-15-minute-time-interval-array-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I don't think it is the same